# Query on spark is not returning any result rows

Tags: apache-spark, benchmarking

I'm not understanding one thing I dont know if you can help but I'll try. To execute the tpch queries on spark how we do that? I'm watching the queries on github and query number 21 seems like in the text below, with three parts.

I don't understand how to execute this, we should execute the three parts separately? I'm doing like that but I'm not getting any results back. The result is being stored on hive table, but not returning on spark.

Example: (query with 3 parts as you can see)

```
insert overwrite table q21_tmp1 
    select l_orderkey, count(distinct l_suppkey), max(l_suppkey) as max_suppkey 
    from lineitem 
    group by l_orderkey;

​ insert overwrite table q21_tmp2 
     select l_orderkey, count(distinct l_suppkey), max(l_suppkey) as max_suppkey 
     from lineitem 
     where l_receiptdate > l_commitdate 
     group by l_orderkey;

insert overwrite table q21_suppliers_who_kept_orders_waiting 
    select s_name, count(1) as numwait 
    from 
        (select s_name 
         from 
             (select s_name, t2.l_orderkey, l_suppkey, count_suppkey, max_suppkey 
              from q21_tmp2 t2 
              right outer join 
                  (select s_name, l_orderkey, l_suppkey  
                   from 
                       (select s_name, t1.l_orderkey, l_suppkey, count_suppkey, max_suppkey 
                        from q21_tmp1 t1 
                        join 
                            (select s_name, l_orderkey, l_suppkey 
                             from orders o 
                             join 
                                 (select s_name, l_orderkey, l_suppkey 
                                  from nation n 
                                  join supplier s on s.s_nationkey = n.n_nationkey 
                                                  and n.n_name = 'SAUDI ARABIA' 
                                  join lineitem l on s.s_suppkey = l.l_suppkey 
                                  where l.l_receiptdate > l.l_commitdate) l1 on o.o_orderkey = l1.l_orderkey and o.o_orderstatus = 'F') l2 on l2.l_orderkey = t1.l_orderkey ) a where (count_suppkey > 1) or ((count_suppkey=1) and (l_suppkey <> max_suppkey)) ) l3 on l3.l_orderkey = t2.l_orderkey ) b where (count_suppkey is null) or ((count_suppkey=1) and (l_suppkey = max_suppkey)) )c group by s_name order by numwait desc, s_name limit 100;
```

Available on: https://github.com/JerryLead/BenchmarkScripts/blob/master/tpch/hive/queries/q21_suppliers_who_kept_orders_waiting.hive

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if I understood right, but after you insert the data in the Hive table your Spark environment is associated to, you can access it by using the Spark SQL API:

```scala
val result = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM q21_tmp1")
result.show()
```

or

```scala
val df = sqlContext.table("q21_tmp1")
val result = df.select("*")
result.show()
```

For more information, you can look at the [Spark Documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html)

Comment: Thanks. I know, Im exeuting queries like that with hivecontext. But the thing is when I execute each part of the query that I have above, the spark processing starts automatically but after executing the last part the last query of the question "insert overwrite table q21_suppliers_who_kept_orders_waiting select..." Im not get any result. So I dont know if this github available queries are supposed to execute like this,

Comment: @Posty These queries are just "insert", my suggestion should be executed after your queries

Comment: So we should execute each part of  above queries, and then after execute each part (each insert) we execute a select * statement  against the result tables? Im asking this for a performance evaluation, what should be the querie times of the tpc benchmark.

Comment: @Posty Oh, ok, now it's a bit clearer. I don't think you can easily adapt the hive script of the link to Spark. In my opinion, you should re-think your approach. One idea is to load the files with `spark-csv`, and then run your queries with HiveContext, but without doing inserts, just querying.